# Celery: running multiple async subtasks causes "never call results.get()" error

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to use Celery to run multiple asynchronous jobs, and while the functions are behaving as they should, I keep getting the following error:

```
RuntimeWarning: Never call result.get() within a task! See http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-synchronous-subtasks
```

Even though I never call results.get(). The way my program works is that Celery is subscribed to a queue, and that kicks off a managerial task. Based on the contents of the message, it will set up 1 or more subtasks and run them as an async group, then wait for them to finish:

```
    job = group(tasks) if len(tasks) == 1 else group(*tasks)
    result = job.apply_async()

    # Wait for jobs to finish.
    cycles = 0
    while not result.ready() and cycles < (timeout / step):
        time.sleep(step)
        cycles += 1

    if not result.successful():
        return False
    return True
```

Do any of these implicitly call `results.get()`? And is it at all viable to have 1 task trigger N many (independent) subtasks? I have looked up similar questions, but none of them seem to be doing quite the same thing as I am here.

Answer (score 0):

So I looked around, and I think the issue is that I am applying the wrong strategy for what I want to do. I want to start N tasks, and then report if they worked or not. However, each sub-task already reports its status to the database and so waiting around to check on that is just keeping the calling worker blocked for no purpose.

I changed the function to this:

```
    job = group(tasks) if len(tasks) == 1 else group(*tasks)
    job.apply_async()
```

And that's it. The tasks start, and the calling function exits, freeing up the worker. The subtasks run as normal and I get no error. What I was trying to do only makes sense if I am trying to make a call that depends on getting the results of each and every subtask.